# Not rendered recaptcha in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, recaptcha

Use of rails 3 recaptcha. In view _form.html.erb insert <%= recaptcha_tags %> But when viewing the page in the browser receives

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=**&amp;error=expression&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

As I understand it is not rendered in the browser. Why '<' instead of < ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<%= raw recaptcha_tags %>`. Or use `html_safe` inside helper.
Explanation here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3